# webview inside NestedScrollView cannot auto load more data

Tags: android, webview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTG2Q.png)

in other broswer,thie web page will load data when scroll to bottom

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you do this. But the reason is when webview nested in scrollView , webview can not catch scrollChange event, so can not load next page automatic。